# WP7 - Change color spinners of DatePicker (Telerik control)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, telerik, datepicker

I am trying to change the color of the spinners for select the day, month and year of the DatePickerobject. I know how I can put the icons V and X in this layout but I don't know how I can change the color of the spinners and maybe will be nice to know how I can change the title and background color of this layout too.

I am working using C#.

Here there is a picture of the element:

[Telerik DatePicker http://blogs.telerik.com/Libraries/Marketing_team/DatePicker3_Small_1.sflb?width=300&height=300&decreaseOnly=true](http://blogs.telerik.com/Libraries/Marketing_team/DatePicker3_Small_1.sflb?width=300&height=300&decreaseOnly=true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is to override the XAML template for the [LooingSelector](https://github.com/Windcape/PhoneToolkit/blob/master/WindowsPhone71/Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit/Themes/Generic.xaml#L421) and the [LoopingSelectorItem](https://github.com/Windcape/PhoneToolkit/blob/master/WindowsPhone71/Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit/Themes/Generic.xaml#L457).